# if-elseif-else statement not working

Tags: php, html

The following code is supposed to check accoroding to the superglobals and output one text field for username. Instead it gives out 3. I checked the code thoroughly, but cannot seem to find any error. I am relatively new to PHP, if someone could guide me.

```html
<? session_start();
// for demo, else these would be in some database
define("USER", "abcde");
define("PASS", "zxcvb");

if (isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"]))
{
    if ($_POST["user"] == USER && $_POST["pass"] == PASS)
    {
        $_SESSION["authenticated"] = true;

        setcookie("user", $_POST["user"], time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);

        $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        $path = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "/\\");
        header("Location: http://$host$path/home.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log In</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td>
                    <? if (isset($_POST["user"])): ?>
                        <input name="user" type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]) ?>">
                    <? elseif (isset($_COOKIE["user"])): ?>
                        <input name="user" type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["user"]) ?>">
                    <? else: ?>
                        <input name="user" type="text" value="">
                    <? endif ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input name="pass" type="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It [works fine for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb226f9071e805f3df7f4ba287730ae6bf61bbc0).

Comment: Are you opening the page through a web-server or from the local file system?

Comment: Its a problem at my end. Some server configuration is notorious.

Comment: @jeroen No, I am using XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using short tags (`<?`) rather than formal tags, which may not be enabled in your php.ini

If you have access to change the php.ini, change `short_open_tag = Off` or `short_open_tag = 0` to `short_open_tag = On` or `short_open_tag = 1` respectively.

Alternatively, add the line `<?php ini_set('short_open_tag','1'); ?>` at the beginning of the file, but this is less than ideal, and would be better by changing all `<?` to `<?php`

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. `if` will not execute multiple paths, e.g:

```
php > if (1==1) { echo 'foo'; } else if (1==1) { echo 'bar'; }
foo
php >
```

even though both conditions evaluate to true, only the FIRST matched condition has its code executed, and then the `if` is done.

If you get all three fields, then most like your PHP is misconfigured and NONE of the php is being executed, and you're getting the raw php output. Since browsers ignore/hide unknown tags, the PHP code is simply not rendered and you see all of the non-php code. e.g. check your browser's "view source", and you'll see the php code there, which means you've got major problems on the server.

Comment: you are right @Marc 
I should have mentioned this before that I am seeing php code in my source. Will you mention what settings I need to posibly change in php.ini to fix this issue?

Comment: nothing. php isn't even running, so php.ini doesn't enter the picture. you need to enable php in your webserver properly.

Comment: Actually support for short tags were turned off. Thanks, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

To execute PHP on localhosts, like XAMP and WAMP, you must use `<?php` at the beginning of the document, or it will output the script like a `<p>` element in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server does not support short tags.
You should try to replace `<?` by `<?php`

See [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) to know more about that.
You can of course allow short tags but it is really not recommended.